# How can I improve my 2 sum algorithm for a range of numbers using a hash table?

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, hashmap

I have developed an algorithm to solve the 2 sum problem using a hash table although its performance is dreadful for huge inputs.

My goal is to find all distinct numbers x,y where -10000<= x+y <=10000. By the way, is the performance of my code O(n*m) where n the size of input and m the number of keys on the map?

Here is my code:

```
import com.google.common.base.Stopwatch;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import static com.google.common.collect.Lists.newArrayList;

public class TwoSum {

    private HashMap<Long, Long> map;
    private ArrayList<Long> Ts;
    private long result = 0L;


    public TwoSum() {
        Ts = newArrayList();
        for(long i = -10000; i < 10001; i++){
            Ts.add(i);
        }

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        map = new HashMap<>();
        while (scan.hasNextLong()) {
            long a = scan.nextLong();
            if (!map.containsKey(a)) {
                map.put(a, a);
            }
        }
    }

    private long count(){
        //long c = 0L;
        for (Long T : Ts) {
            long t = T;
            for (Long x : map.values()) {
                long y = t - x;
                if (map.containsValue(y) && y != x) {
                    result++;
                }
                //System.out.println(c++);
            }
        }
        return result / 2;
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        TwoSum s = new TwoSum();
        Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.createStarted();
        System.out.println(s.count());
        stopwatch.stop();
        System.out.println("time:" + stopwatch);

    }
}
```

sample input:

-7590801
-3823598
-5316263
-2616332
-7575597
-621530
-7469475
1084712
-7780489
-5425286
3971489
-57444
1371995
-5401074
2383653
1752912
7455615
3060706
613097
-1073084
7759843
7267574
-7483155
-2935176
-5128057
-7881398
-637647
-2607636
-3214997
-8253218
2980789
168608
3759759
-5639246
555129
-4489068
44019
2275782
-3506307
-8031288
-213609
-4524262
-1502015
-1040324
3258235
32686
1047621
-3376656
7601567
-7051390
6633993
-6245148
4994051
-4259178
856589
6047000
1785511
4449514
-1177519
4972172
8274315
7725694
-4923179
5076288
-876369
-7663790
1613721
4472116
-4587501
3194726
6195357
-3364248
-113737
6260410
1974241
3174620
3510171
7289166
4532581
-6650736
-3782721
7007010
6007081
-7661180
-1372125
-5967818
516909
-7625800
-2700089
-7676790
-2991247
2283308
1614251
-4619234
2741749
567264
4190927
5307122
-5810503
-6665772

output: 6

Answer (score 3):

The gist of your algorithm can be rewritten in pseudocode as:

```
for all integers t from -10k to 10k,
    for all map keys x,
        if t - x in map, and t is not 2*x,
            count ++
return count / 2
```

You can easily improve this a bit:

```
for all integers t from -10k to 10k,
    for the lower half of keys x in ascending order such that t is not 2*x
        if t - x in map,
            count ++
```

This makes it go twice as fast (you no longer double-count). However, you need to sort your inputs to ensure map keys in ascending order. You can add them into a TreeSet and then move it into a LinkedHashSet. Using Sets is better than Maps if you do not care about the values, and all the information is in the keys.

Running time is still O(inputs * range), since you have two nested loops, one with `range` iterations and the other with half your `input`. This is a fundamental shortcoming of the algorithm, and no amount of optimization will fix it.

Comment: downvoter, care to explain why? I may be able to fix it.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I suppose `t is not 2*x` is coming from the requirement for distinct numbers, although it is unclear from the problem description what that means. You assuming `x + y = t ∀ x, y ⊂ map and x ≠ y` but I can think of other interpretations. If `x = 30000 and y = -20000`, then `x = -20000 and y = 30000` are not to be counted. Or may be `x = 30000 and y = -15000` are not to be counted because we've seen `x` once.

Comment: I agree that the problem statement is somewhat ambiguous, but only the OP can clarify what was meant. The issues you raise could, if confirmed, be easily fixed in the pseudo-code: multiply by 2 to count both x,y and y,x (where x<y), for example. The `distinct numbers` in the statement would prohibit `t=2*x` to be considered, though.

Answer (score 0):

The question is an assignment from [Algorithms: Design and Analysis](https://lagunita.stanford.edu/courses/course-v1:Engineering+Algorithms1+SelfPaced/about)
 - an online course offered by Stanford University and taught by Prof. Tim Roughgarden. I happen to be taking the same course.

The usual solution for looking up `t - i` in a hash table is `O(n)` for a single `t`, but doing that `20001 * 1000000` times results in roughly 20 billion lookups!

A better solution is to create a sorted set `xs` from the input file, and `∀i ∈ xs`, find all numbers from `xs` in the range `[-10000 - i, 10000 - i]`. Since a sorted set, by definition, doesn't have duplicates, so we don't need to worry about any number in the range being equal to `i`. There's one gotcha though, which is really unclear in the problem statement. It is not only sufficient to find unique `(x, y) ∀ x, y ∈ xs`, but also that their sum is unique. Obviously, 2 unique numbers may produce equal sums (e.g. 2 + 4 = 1 + 5 = 6). Thus, we need to keep track of the sums too.

Lastly, we can stop once we go past 5000, since there can't be any more numbers to the right that add up to less than 10000.

Here's a Scala solution:

```
def twoSumCount(xs: SortedSet[Long]): Int = {
  xs
    .foldLeft(collection.mutable.Set.empty[Long]) { (sums, i) =>
      if (i < TenThou / 2) {
        xs
          // using from makes it slower
          .range(-TenThou - i, TenThou - i + 1)
          .map(_ + i)
          // using diff makes it slower
          .withFilter(y => !sums.contains(y))
          // adding individual elements is faster than using
          // diff/filter/filterNot and adding all using ++=
          .foreach(sums.add)
      }
      sums
    }
    .size
}
```

Benchmark:

```
cores: 8
hostname: ***
name: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
osArch: x86_64
osName: Mac OS X
vendor: Azul Systems, Inc.
version: 11.0.1+13-LTS
Parameters(file -> 2sum): 116.069441 ms
```